# Using room for only one user object?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm writing an Android app that allows user to login and logout. When logged in the User object should be stored in Room database. And when logged out the User object should be deleted from the db.

How can I ensure that only one user object is stored in Room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very broad. I am not sure what properties your user will have, e.g unique id, or some other uniquely identify properties.

In case, if user class has a property, such as unique id, make it primary key in your room table. Then, in your insert / save doa methods, declare onConflict resolution methods, you can handle it with several options.

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
```

To ignore duplication, so it allow duplication. Instead of ABORT enum, you may use REPLACE to replace, INGORE, FAIL, ROLLBACK and etc.

In case you do not have such uniquely identifying properties, you may create one by hashing properties that user class has, if it is required. However, not suggested.

However, it seems like you want to handle session management in your app. For such session management, there is not need to database. You may use SharedPreference, which is usually used for such purposes.

Comment: Should i set a default primary key or let room to autogenerate primary key?

Comment: If you may have uniquely identifying property you can mark it with @PrimaryKey to make it primary key. Or auto generate it.